# How to create a new List base on identical value of Object

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list like this:

```
[
    {
      "group": "A",
      "fruit": [
        {"name": "Apple", "amount": 2, "source": "Super Market"},
        {"name": "Banana", "amount": 3, "color": "Green"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "B",
      "fruit": [
        {"name": "Apple", "amount": 5}
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "C",
      "fruit": [
        {"name": "Banana", "amount": 4}
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I want to create a new list base on identical `"name"` and sum their `"amount"` like this:

```
[
    {"name": "Apple", "amount": 7},
    {"name": "Banana", "amount": 7}
  ]
```

### UPDATE QUESTION

The first question has been answered perfectly by Ουιλιαμ Αρκευα, however, to avoid creating a new post, I would like to ask the second question right here:

Still the same example above, but I have one more list as follows:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "amount": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Banana",
    "amount": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Cherry",
    "amount": 2
  }
]
```

so how can I merge the new list into the old list with the identical `"name"` and sum `"amount"` to get the result as below

```
[
    {"name": "Apple", "amount": 9},
    {"name": "Banana", "amount": 9},
    {"name": "Cherry", "amount": 2}
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import 'dart:convert';

typedef JMap = Map<String, dynamic>;
typedef JList = List<JMap>;

const raw = '''
[
  {
    "group": "A",
....
    ]
  }
]
''';

const JList extra = [
  {'name': 'Apple', 'amount': 2},
  {'name': 'Banana', 'amount': 2},
  {'name': 'Cherry', 'amount': 2}
];

void main(List<String> args) {
  final data = jsonDecode(raw) as List;
  var count = <String, int>{};
  final add = (String k, int v) => count[k] = v + (count[k] ?? 0);

  data.forEach((m) => (m['fruit'] as List).forEach((n) => add(n['name'], n['amount'])));
  extra.forEach((m) => add(m['name'], m['amount']));

  final total = count.entries.map<JMap>((me) => {'name': me.key, 'amount': me.value}).toList();
  
  print(total);
}
```

Result:

```
[{name: Apple, amount: 9}, {name: Banana, amount: 9}, {name: Cherry, amount: 2}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works perfectly, I have updated the question, hope you can help me again

Comment: Answer updated. This is not hard, you should think a little more about your problem.